# Linear regression for body fat equations (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I have very little experience with MATLAB, and i'm trying to develop a system for bioimpedance measurement. I intend use the MATLAB function mvregress to obtain a regression equation for body fat.

According to this [article](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/f2014/smb435_pkl25/webpage/), known values of body fat, voltage, age, and weight was passed to the function mvregress which outputs a vector of coefficients that weight the independent variables (age, weight, and voltage) in order to closely match the collected dependent variable (body fat). For simplicity, the ADC input value was used instead of raw voltage.

My question is, in a practical way, how can I get an equation similar to this (obtained in the article mentioned above):

Males: body_fat = 0.0923 * weight + 0.1605 * age - 0.0263 * voltage

Females: body_fat = 0.1871 * weight + 0.5800 * age - 0.0920 * voltage

From values of body fat, voltage (decimal value), age, and weight, using the function mvregress. I read the mvregress documentation, but I could not understand.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want a multiple linear regression, rather than a multivariate linear regression. As such you should try `LinearModel.fit` rather than `mvregress`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, I think you want a multiple linear regression, rather than a multivariate linear regression. As such you should try `LinearModel.fit` rather than `mvregress`.

If you have your data in the variables `weight`, `age`, `volt` and `fat` (and ensure that the variables are all columns, not rows), then the following should give you what you're after:

`mdl = LinearModel.fit([weight, age, volt], fat, 'Intercept',false)`